# SQL current_timestamp+14

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am having problem creating a table.
Here's what I am trying to do:
I have a table that automatically inserts current time and a current time + 14 days.

Below is my code:

```
'''
create table borrowedbook (
studentEmail varchar(255) not null,
bookId varchar(255) not null,
borrowedDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT  current_timestamp(),
returnedDate datetime,
dueDate datetime NOT null default current_timestamp()+14,

FOREIGN KEY (studentEmail) REFERENCES student(studentEmail),
FOREIGN KEY (bookId) REFERENCES book(bookId)
);
'''
```

I need to make dueDate field work.

need help!

edit: I am using DBeaver, mysql

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using dbeaver

Comment: `dbeaver` is a universal database tool, are you using mysql or mssql or postgres?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: Did you try `NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_add(time_stamp, interval)`:

```
create table borrowedbook (
studentEmail varchar(255) not null,
bookId varchar(255) not null,
borrowedDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT  current_timestamp(),
returnedDate datetime,

dueDate datetime NOT null default DATE_ADD(current_timestamp, INTERVAL 14 DAY),

FOREIGN KEY (studentEmail) REFERENCES student(studentEmail),
FOREIGN KEY (bookId) REFERENCES book(bookId)
);
```